# Kafka streams DSL: aggregate, enrich and send through

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

we have the following problem to solve with Kafka Streams:

1- get a message. Each message is stamped with eventId (message updates event) and correlationId (unique for each message).

2- aggregate some state from that message (based on eventId) and append it to already existing state in local store

3- enrich that message for full aggregated state for that event and send it through to output topic

Point is we can't really lose a single message, and it must alway enrich the incoming message with the latest aggregated state (which we actually evaluate during message processing).

From what I've seen so far we cant just use simple aggregation (something like that:)

```scala
stateMessageStream
  .map((k, v) => new KeyValue[String, StateMessage](k, v))
  .mapValues[StateMessageWithMarkets](sm => {StateMessageWithMarkets(Some(sm), extract(sm))})
  .groupBy((k, _) => k, stringSerde, marketAggregatorSerde)
  .aggregate[StateMessageWithMarkets](() => StateMessageWithMarkets(), (_, v, aggregatedState) => aggregatedState.updateModelMarketsWith(v), marketAggregatorSerde, kafkaStoreName)
  .to(stringSerde, marketAggregatorSerde, kafkaOutTopic)
```

because aggregation produces new records only in intervals, and that would mean for two incoming messages we might generate only single aggregated output message (so we lost one message)

My second attempt how to implement this was basically two streams, one for aggregation, second for plain messages. At the end we can join two streams back together using join operation, based on correlationId as a key - that we can match the right state with the right message:

```scala
val aggregatedStream : KStream[String, MarketAggregator] = stateMessageStream
  .map((k, v) => new KeyValue[String, StateMessage](k, v))
  .mapValues[StateMessage](v => {
    log.debug("Received State Message, gameId: " + v.metadata().gtpId() + ", correlationId: " + v.correlationId)
    v})
  .mapValues[MarketAggregator](sm => {MarketAggregator(sm.correlationId, extract(sm))})
  .groupBy((k, v) => k, stringSerde, marketAggregatorSerde)
  .aggregate[MarketAggregator](() => MarketAggregator(), (_, v, aggregatedState) => aggregatedState.updateModelMarketsWith(v), marketAggregatorSerde, kafkaStoreName)
  .toStream((k, v) => v.correlationId)

stateMessageStream
  .selectKey[String]((k, v) => v.correlationId)
  .leftJoin[MarketAggregator, StateMessageWithMarkets](aggregatedStream, (stateMessage : StateMessage, aggregatedState : MarketAggregator) => StateMessageWithMarkets(Some(stateMessage), aggregatedState.modelMarkets, stateMessage.correlationId),
      JoinWindows.of(10000),
      stringSerde, stateMessageSerde, marketAggregatorSerde)
  .mapValues[StateMessageWithMarkets](v => {
        log.debug("Producing aggregated State Message, gameId: " + v.stateMessage.map(_.metadata().gtpId()).getOrElse("unknown") +
          ", correlationId: " + v.stateMessage.map(_.correlationId).getOrElse("unknown"))
          v
        })
  .to(stringSerde, stateMessageWithMarketsSerde, kafkaOutTopic)
```

However, that does not seem to be working either - for two incoming messages I still get just single message with latest aggregated state on the output topic.

Can someone please explain why and what the right solution would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use approach one and get an output message for each input message by disabling the cache. In your `StreamsConfig` you just set the value of `StreamConfig#CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG` to zero.

For more details, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management